# Why can't I stop the default action on my click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

```
$("#city-button-panel a")
    .click(function () {
    preventDefault();
    var $link = $(this);
    getCityContentAjax($link);
});
```

But it's not allowing me to preventDefault and it gives a syntax error

Here is what the elements look like that are deep inside #city-button-panel:

```
<a href="/City/1555009O" id="btn-49">49</a>
```

Comment: does adding onclick="return false" to the tag instead prevent it?

Comment: @technosaurus that's not the desired course of action. This attribute should be rather left alone.

Comment: Are you sure it is giving you a syntax error?

Comment: @JanDvorak some items can't be overridden, it was just a quick check to see if that were the case before wasting time writing code that would never work

Comment: I updated my question. Syntax error solved but it still trys to call the URL directly when the user clicks on the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `preventDefault` on the event you're being passed. Any other `preventDefault` is either undefined or does something else. Try:

```
$("#city-button-panel a")
        .click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault(); 
            var $link = $(this);
            getCityContentAjax($link);
        });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vatjK/

Note that the handler has to return successfully in order for the `preventDefault` to work. If `getCityContentAjax` throws an exception, the default action can not be prevented without also preventing the exception from propagating. You can, however, do this (if you can't fix `getCityContentAjax`):

```
$("#city-button-panel a")
        .click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault(); 
            var $link = $(this);
            try{
                getCityContentAjax($link);
            }catch(e){
                console && console.error(e);
                alert("Look at the console!!!"); // optional
            }
        });
```

There is no syntax error in this piece of code. If the browser thinks otherwise, you may have syntax error *before* the code. Note there's a difference between a syntax error (unmatched parentheses and such) and a reference error (a function in the global scope does not exist).

Comment: there's no syntax error now but it is stil doing the action and calling the URL directly as well as calling the getCity.

Comment: @Anne It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/vatjK/ . Perhaps `getCityContentAjax` causes an exception, preventing the event from being prevented?

Comment: @Anne can you provide a test case where it fails? I'm willing to investigate.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I feel rather stupid as I have never even seen a try - catch in Javascrikpt. thanks very much for teaching me.

Comment: @Anne so there _was_ an exception? Note that you should remove the cause, not catch and discard the resulting exception. Unlike Java, Javascript does not use exceptions to indicate exceptional states.

Answer (score 0):

here is plain javascript (+html) version

```
<head>
  <script>
     function theClick(url,ev){
       getCityContentAjax(url);
       ev.preventDefault();
     }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <a onclick="theClick(this,event)" href="url.html">a link</a>
</body>
```